# Show Tile on top of selected BottomNavigationBarItem in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to show a bar on selected BottomNavigationBarItem as shown here. this is what I need exactly.

```
BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              currentIndex: currentIndex,
              fixedColor: Colors.blue[800],
              onTap: (value) {

              },
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.shopify,
                      size: 21.0,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Abc',

                    )),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.shop,
                      size: 21.0,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Second Tab',

                    )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Refernce image

[image: Refernce image]

Comment: With default `BottomNavigationBar` widget you can't do that, but you can always create your own widget.

Answer (score 0):

The default `BottomNavigationBar` in `Flutter` doesn't support this behaviour. To get this kind of behaviour for `BottomNavigationBar` in Flutter. You have to create your own widget.

But the package below helps you to achieve that with ease. Check the link below for the package:

[Styled BottomNavigationBar](https://pub.dev/packages/titled_navigation_bar)